# Meaning of comma in between a surname and first name

Tags: meaning

What does the comma mean when placed in between surname and first name when writing an initial?

For example - Elisabeth, George - what does the comma indicate?

Comment: Net-net:  When a "Western" name is being listed with "last name" first (as when creating an alphabetical list), the convention is to write *last_name, first_name ... whatever_else*.  Thus the above example is for a person named "George Elisabeth".

Answer (score 3):

A couple of problems here.  Your example doesn't have an initial.  And the name of the author is Eli**z**abeth George.  In references that place the surname first, a comma is used to separate the last name of an author from the initial of her first name.  This style is often used in the author lists in scholarly papers.  If this were the case for the mystery writer, her name would be cited as "George, E."  If she were to be referred to by her full name "Susan Elizabeth George," the cite would be "George, S. E."

Comment: Looks, from the way the OP has written it, as though it is a man, Mr George Elisabeth.

Comment: The OP has; she's not.  Go here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_George

Comment: @deadrat They're both such common names that without more info we have no way to say whether it's Elizabeth George or George Elizabeth.

Comment: They're both common names, but not together.  A US phone lookup finds 3 George Elizabeths and 1 George Elisabeth.  Likely no one would put any of the four in a last-name first listing.  But perhaps the OP was merely using an example he made up.  In any case, it doesn't matter to the answer to his question.

Comment: I think @WS2's point was simply that when a comma is used like this, the surname goes first, so "Elizabeth, George" **looks** like a way of writing "George Elizabeth", regardless of what was intended or whether such a person actually exists.